# Mysql unresponsive after pressing enter on simple query

Tags: mysql

MySql stops responding once I execute this simple query to add a new column(called `held_by`) to my table called project.

All I am seeing after pressing enter is my cursor on the next line.

MySql is not even displaying the `query OK. X rows affected` message.

Is there a setting that I have to enable to avoid this or what else should be done to make it execute?

Here's the code:

```
alter table project add held_by varchar(30);
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible that the table is being held locked by a transaction on another session. Not sure if [Identify Locked Tables](https://oracle-base.com/articles/mysql/mysql-identify-locked-tables) can help here.

Comment: Actually it executes only selection queries.Does not execute drop or alter queries.Also i installed mysql on wampserver only recently .

Comment: Update:My query to drop the table worked after 11 minutes

Comment: Not sure if you saw my comment. Was the table locked?

Comment: Well i tried the show open tables command and it showed the table project as having both In_use and Name_locked as 0.Thanks for willing to help since i need this solved in order to proceed with my computer science project